# Remove nulls from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method what should delete values from an array...

```
public Application[] deleteApp(String id) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.apps.length; i++) {
            if (this.apps[i] != null && this.apps[i].getId().equals(id)) {
                this.apps[i] = null;
                if (this.apps[i] == null)
                    count++;
            }
        }
        Application[] withoutNulls = new Application[this.apps.length - count];
        int index = 0;
        for (Application app : this.apps) {
            if (app != null) {
                withoutNulls[index] = app;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return withoutNulls;
    }
```

But final result is smth like:

```
Application[] app = {app1, app2, null};
```

**What's wrong?** I'm counting nulls, creating new array[sizeOfArray - countOfNulls], and recording only not-null values :(

upd
I have a test of that.

```
@Test
    public void deleteAppTest() {
        Tracker tracker = new Tracker();
        Application testing_1 = new Application();
        Application testing_2 = new Application();
        Application[] test = {testing_1};
        tracker.addApp(testing_1);
        tracker.addApp(testing_2);
        tracker.deleteApp(testing_2.getId());
        assertThat(tracker.showApps(), is(test));
```

But method does not pass the test. 
Expected: is []
     but: was [, null]

Comment: Final result of *what*? What is your input and What is your action that causes this result?

Comment: My guess is that you are looking at the modified `apps`, not at the return value of this method (`withoutNulls`). The code itself looks like it should work.

Comment: In any case, you did properly indent your code, so it's pretty easy to see that you put your check `if (this.apps[i] == null)` in the wrong place. You should turn it into an `else if` clause of the preceding if-statement `if (this.apps[i] != null && this.apps[i].getId().equals(id))`

Comment: Also note that the method does not handle `null` that were already in `apps` at the beginning.

Comment: app wont become null... try nullcheck for getId()

Answer (score 0):

Try with Lambdas

```
   public Application[] deleteApp(String id) {
      List<Application> result = Arrays.asList(apps).stream().
            filter(app -> app != null &&!id.equals(app.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
      return result.toArray(new Application[result.size()]);
  }
```

Here it is as @Erwin Bolwidt suggested

```
public Application[] deleteApp(String id) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < this.apps.length; i++) {
          if (this.apps[i] != null && this.apps[i].getId().equals(id)) {
              this.apps[i] = null;
              count++;
          }
          // Move this if out into an else if
          else if (this.apps[i] == null){
             count++;
          }
      }
      Application[] withoutNulls = new Application[this.apps.length - count];
      int index = 0;
      for (Application app : this.apps) {
          if (app != null) {
              withoutNulls[index] = app;
              index++;
          }
      }
      return withoutNulls;
  }
```